# How to authenticate a user based on a certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

On a Certificate provider, StartSSL, when you register, you put in your email and a password. They generate a certificate (.pfx) which you need to download and install into your browser.

Which was pointed out in comments that it is a Client Certificate.

So when you click login, in Chrome for example, a window popups and asks you which certificate to use. I could have several client certificates and log into separate accounts based on what I select. They warn that if you loose the certificate then you can't log in to the site without them regenerating a new certificate.

I am would like to do this using C# - I would like to generate a client certificate and then use it later to log in as admin without typing in a password.

What are the mechanics of this? How can generate certificates and use them to log in to my site? I would like to  do this on a MVC C# site. I don't mind if I need to generate self signed certificates, its only for my own use. At least it gets rid of password forms and brute force attacks.

Comment: A server-side certificate does not authenticate a user, that's a client-side certificate. Your question is unclear about what kind of certificates you're talking about.

Comment: Your server's ssl cert authenticates your server TO the user, not the other way around. It's the exact same type of cert that (say) amazon.com uses to prove that the site you're viewing in your browser really is amazon.

Comment: Because I am unsure how its done. How can it be a client side certificate? What happens, how does the site ask for a certificate? And what information does the client send to the server? A fingerprint? A code? I don't understand.

Comment: I can select another certificate and it will log me in to another account.... so how does that work?

Comment: the first paragraph of the question replies to both the first 2 comments.
He is talking about client-side certificates used to authorize the user to the server (which I didn't even know existed).

Comment: OK, So I will update the question to specify client side certificates. I never knew about this either and think its great for my personal sites.

Comment: yes. I think you should delete the entire second paragraph of your question since (I think) this has nothing to do with the certificate you have installed on your server.

Comment: Updated.. Can you un-down vote me please?

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly simple, the certificate requirement is an option of the SSL handshake.

First you need to go to SSL options on IIS and check the option to accept and **require** certificates. This is enough for browsers to automatically pop up the cert selection window and the communication is mutually secured by both server and client certificates.

https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc753983%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Then comes the request pipeline. You either need a httpmodule or you just provide a handler for the global application's `AuthenticateRequest` event. There, you refer to the `Request.ClientCertificate`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524668%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You read the certificate's unique properties, for example the thumbprint and you use your local database to find a user record that corresponds to the certificate and you set up the `Principal` for the request lifetime accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. How can I generate the certificates. I have the private key of the top SSL certificate, or has that nothing to do with generating client certificates?

Comment: Client certificates have nothing to do with the server ssl certificates. You can generate certificates in any possible way, even manually with makecert or you can just ask your clients to use their ceritificates they already own. The only important element is the mapping from cert thumbprints to actual users.